# How to make current page with different style (PHP ?page href)?

Tags: php, css, for-loop, pagination, echo

My piece of code.
And problem now are about styling, i just want style page number, wich is open, like a active id, if page open, then that number is in different color or smth else.

I need make a new variable? Or what, i just try to add  but its wont work, it only works if at the end i write echo $page; , then it show style on this, but i need on links, numbers.

```
<?php
                    if($total_pages > 1){
                        if($page != 1){
                          echo '<a href="pardod.php?page='.($page-1).'">&nbsp; < &nbsp;</a>';
                        }
                            for($number=1;$number<=$total_pages;$number++)
                            {
                                echo '<a href="?page='.$number.'">'.$number.'</a>';
                            }
                        if($page != $total_pages){
                          echo '<a href="pardod.php?page='.($page+1).'">&nbsp; > &nbsp;</a>';
                        }
                    }

                ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
$currentPageNumber = $_GET['page'];
for($number=1;$number<=$total_pages;$number++){

    $currentPageStyle = '';
    if($number == $currentPageNumber){
        $currentPageStyle = 'style="color:red"';
    }

    echo '<a href="?page='.$number.'" '.$currentPageStyle.'>'.$number.'</a>';
}
```